# User login system is not hashing and comparing password with record Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project and I have created the user login features for new users. I am having an issue with the login system once the user has created an account.

The issue is that django is hashing the password when the new account is created. I think that when I try logging into one of the accounts, it is not hashing the password and then checking to see if the passwords match.

Is that what is going on or is it something that i am doing..

Here is the views.py file:

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            username = cd['username']
            password = cd['password']
            valid_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if valid_user:
                if password == valid_user.password:
                    request.session['username'] = username
                    return redirect('/')
                else:
                    message = 'Password does not match the username'
            else:
                message = 'Invalid Username'
            parameters = {
                'message':message,
                'form':form,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/login.html', parameters)
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        message = 'Login Below'
        parameters = {
            'form':form,
            'message':message,
        }
        return render(request, 'tabs/login.html', parameters)
```

html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py file:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=22)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=22, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Here is a few of the users and passwords that i have created ...

```
steven -- pbkdf2_sha256$20000$z2DdGDm5D8Yu$v0nwWWj/2qslNUUTmYMd1ePBqyjpHoWM76AY5k11f9o=

josh -- pbkdf2_sha256$20000$cMy01yE10w7I$O39pRqQsb/se+E8ttvEn9JRlb8qB4xrfS1GRKQKHA2Q=

Moe -- pbkdf2_sha256$20000$hJysyabGcxpP$As4cvzWu2x+YjJ4RvP8EjS2dxhusQwuTlPvS7av35Ys=

omarjandali -- hellohello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely agree with NeErAj KuMaR. And you don't need `forms` for login. Just keep it simple.

```
# views.py

from django.contrib import auth

def login_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            auth.login(request, user)
        else:
            message = 'Invalid Username'
    parameters = {
        'message':message,
    }
    return render(request, 'tabs/login.html', parameters)
```

Now modify the code in login.html

```
# login.html

... 
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
...
```

Comment: question. what i have done when a account is created as well as user is logged in, it saves the username in the session and when they logout it takes the username out of the session and every page will check to see if the username is in the session. is that method or the auth.login method better to use in django...

Comment: Also what would be the import statement if i use the auth.authentication @Simplans

Comment: If you want to check whether the user is login or not use this code  "if request.user.is_authenticated():"

Comment: "auth.authenticate" is used to validate the username and password and "auth.login" is used for login the user

Comment: i am using the auth.authenticate but it is saying that auth is not defined. i need to add the import statement but I am not sure what the import statement is for the auth.authenticate... do you know what it is @Simplans

Comment: I mentioned it above in the answer "from django.contrib import auth"

Comment: I figured it out.. i just took out the `auth.` from the `auth.authenticate` and used the `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate` @Simplans

Comment: If you import like that don't forget to import login

Comment: yeah i have that imported as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to use django authenticate method for check password

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password) 

if user is not None: 
    login(request, user) # Redirect to a success page. ...

else:
     # invalid password
```

Answer (score 0):

**DON'T** CHECK **RAW** PASSWORD!!!

Django has innate password validator, so you have to use it, not make your own(especially **DO NOT SAVE** raw password!!!!)

For security reason, you should not save user's password in raw.

When you're using django's user like `auth.User`, django encrypt user's password 30,000 times by SHA2, with salts. It means nobody can read raw password when lookup DB's password column.

If you're making your own User model, I suggest you to use your code like this:

```
# maybe in your views.py
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        user = UserModel.objects.get(username=username)
        if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
            return user
```

If you're using django's user model(`auth.User`), just use `authenticate` function in `auth.User`, try like this:

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

```
# your views.py
def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

> Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in